# Error while deploying SiteDotCom

Tags: community, deployment, site.com

I am getting `Error: Cannot import data from a newer release!` while deploying siteDotCom from one sandbox to another sandbox.
Version of source sandbox is 44 and target sandbox is 43.Could this be the reason for the error.

Below is the `site-meta.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SiteDotCom xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<label>testSite</label>
<siteType>ChatterNetworkPicasso</siteType>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely because your source org version is ahead of the Target org version .

There are not much options for you than to wait for sometime till both the sandboxes are of same version if you are using changesets .

If you are retrieving using package.xml and an IDE you can try to retrieve with package.xml version v43.0 and deploy using v43.0.

Comment: I tried with your suggestion but still the issue persists. Now I am thinking if there could is any template version difference in community.

Comment: Does enabling [ExperienceBundle](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.communities_dev.meta/communities_dev/communities_dev_migrate_expbundle.htm#!) allow you to navigate around this restriction?

Comment: No it won’t let you navigate this restriction